# Anomaly Detection over multivariate data containing Nominal and numerical predictors

Tags: data-cleaning, correlation, autoencoder, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I am trying to implement Anomaly Detection over a multivariate dataset having nominal and numerical predictors.

Dataset has following pattern:
[image: Data pattern]

If we consider the below sample records, category_id, currency, and product_id are nominal predictors, whereas price is a numerical variable.

My model is **able to identify** the anomaly in the price for '_id=4' because the price range for different products for the *particular combination of category_id-currency-product_id* is between 10-500EUR.

But it is **not able to identify** anomalies for product_id=1, product_id=2 or product_id=3 as they have unusual category_id or currency or product_id.

[image: Types of Anomalies]

Correlation matrix for dataset:

[image: Correlation matrix for dataset]

I am applying **'Multiple Correspondance Analysis(MCA)'** over nominal predictors and reducing these 3 predictors to 2 predictors.

Algorithm:
I have tried with OC-SVM, Isolation Forest, and Autoencoders, but none perform as expected.

Some of the resources that I have checked but to no help:
[Unsupervised Anomaly Detection with Mixed Numeric and Categorical Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320398/unsupervised-anomaly-detection-with-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data)

[Anomaly Detection/Novelty detection](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67089/anomaly-detection-novelty-detection)

**I am not able to understand where I am making the mistake: Data pre-processing OR Algorithm OR something else?**

**I would highly appreciate any help here.**

[You can review my code here.](https://github.com/dhavalsimaria/MachineLearning/blob/master/Anomaly%20Detection/Anomaly_Detection.ipynb)

Comment: How are you encoding nominal variables?

Comment: @bonfab Initially I tried OneHotEncoding but that's not helpful in long run as number of classes will only increase.e.g.diff. currencies. Then I used Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA) over the 3 nominal attributes.